# Change size of HTML5 canvas drawings but maintain canvas dimensions

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Here is the scenario:

- Suppose the dimensions of the canvas element is set to a max height and max width and obviously does not occupy the entire screen
- We can make drawings made in the canvas larger on events:

```
   function onMouseMove(e)
   { 
      e.preventDefault();
      if (pinching) {
         resizeDrawings();
      }  
   }
   function resizeDrawings();
   {
     //stuff happens
     const context = currentCanvas.current.getContext('2d');
     //canvas operations

   }
```

Basically, i want the canvas to overflow and become scrollable if its own contents become too big to fit on it's own dimensions.

Comment: A canvas is just basically a set of points - there isn't a concept of 'content' in the sense that there is with say a div element. Could you describe in more detail what you want to happen - especially what would make the canvas 'overflow'?

Comment: Basically the canvas is encapsulated with a div, with their dimensions always fitted into the parent dimension. When we "pinch" the canvas, i want the drawings to globally look bigger and if needed the canvas becomes scrollable so the canvas doesn't seem to change size and the proportions of the site stay the same.